# iOS update location even when app is terminated

Tags: ios, background, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to update users location even when app is terminated. I added maps, and background mode --> Location update to my .plist, and I set an local notification that will fire when location is updated. But it never got fired. I have this in *AppDelegat.h*:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
```

and in *AppDelegate.m*

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

---

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

 UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
[notification setAlertBody:@"Location update!"];
[notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  defaultTimeZone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    }
```

I tested this code on simulator with Freeway drive as location and it doesn't work.

---

**EDIT**

If I put the code under `applicationDidEnterBackground` authorization request will close the second it's opened, because I'm using `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I know it's tracking location 24h because there's GPS symbol even when app is terminated.

---

**EDIT 2**

After testing it on my phone the code works. It wakes terminated app and sends local notification. It doesn't work on simulator but works in real life(device) :)

Comment: How long did you wait for in freeway drive? 
According to Apple:

"Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters or more from its previous notification. It should not expect notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner."
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Comment: From start to the end of the ride, and I didn't get any notification.

Comment: wait why is you code under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? Should it not be under applicationDidEnterBackground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using CLLocationManagerDelegate's deprecated function:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation { 
}
```

Instead you should implement

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
}
```

Comment: Above code will work only for foreground and background not in suspended condition .

Comment: Actually @iThink as the OP called `[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]` I would expect this delegate to also get called in the background when a significant location change does occur.